# Template with default parameters and specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have this piece of code:

```
template <class T = double>
class Mat {

};

template <>
class Mat<double> {

};

/*****************************************************************************/
// main
/*****************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char * const argv []) {

  Mat mat1;  // work

  Mat<Mat> mat2; // error

  return 0;

}
```

The compiler using -std=gnu++17 give me back on "Mat mat2":

***"Use of class template 'Mat' requires template arguments"***

I do not understand why.

***Update:***

Someone suggested me to use the notation

```
Mat<Mat<>>
```

However I pretty sure that the second empty <> should be superfluous in C++17

Comment: `Mat<Mat<>> Mat;`.

Comment: The second pair of `<>` are not superfluous. If you only pass `Mat` then you will pass the class `template` named Mat, not the `class` Mat with it's template parameter defaulted to double. And this causes an error since your template parameter accepts types only, not templates. Maybe search for template template parameters to better understand.

Comment: `I pretty sure that the second empty <> is superfluous` no, it's not. It is mandatory, and the compiler made that quite clear.

Comment: I do not agree with you seem the in C++17 you can void <>

Answer (score 1):

From what I read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), since C++17 you don't neet to provide `<>` if the type can be deduced from initializers, that's all. So you'd need an initializer if you want deduction without the `<>`.

So you either have to do something like that, as Quentin said in comments :

```
Mat<Mat<>> mat2;
```

Or define some constructors that will allow for type deduction. Here is how you could go about it:

```
template <class T = double>
class Mat
{
public:
   Mat(std::initializer_list<T> l) { for (const auto& v : l) std::cout << v << std::endl; }

   friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Mat<T>& mat) {
      os << "Mat object" << endl;
      return os;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char * const argv[]) {

   Mat mat1{ 1.0, 5.6 };  // T = double deduced from initializer list
   Mat mat2({ Mat{1.2, 3.6} }); // T = Mat<double> deduced from initizalizer

   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1
5.6
1.2
3.6
Mat object
```

Comment: Ok.  But what you mean with "an initializer"?

Comment: I mean the two first examples in the page. In those the type of the values provided at initialization is used by the compiler to deduce the type of the constructor parameters (and thus the template parameter). In your example case you can't use initialization to have type deduction since you have no constructor using your type T. (Hence you have no choice, in your example, but to use an additional <>)

Comment: Sorry I'm not so expert. I do not understand what you mean, There is a way to use my notation?

Comment: I have edited to clarify my suggestion. I hope this helps. I must admit, in your example without initialization, I am not sure why your compiler seems to deduce correctly the mat1 type to its default double, and not the mat2 type. In my compiler set to C++17, error is triggered for both mat1 and mat2 when omitting <>.